# JSON to HIVE ingestion

Tags: json, mongodb, hadoop, hive

> add jar /path to/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
>
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student
>
> (    id  int,    student_id INT,    type STRING,    score DOUBLE
>
> )
>
> STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
>
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'mongo.columns.mapping'='{ "id":"_id", 
>   "student_id":"student_id", "type":"type","score":"score" }' )
>
> TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://****-**-**-****.nam.nsroot.net:*****/admin.student');

I am able to successfully run the code and ingest data. But the "id" field gets populated as NULL. 
Should i change the data type ? I tried STRING as well. Got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mongo-hadoop Hive SerDe](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage#serialization-and-deserialization), ObjectId corresponds to a special instance of STRUCT.

A Hive field corresponding to an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) must be a STRUCT with the fields `oid`, a STRING, and `bsontype`, an INT, and nothing else. The `oid` is the string of the ObjectId while the `bsontype` should always [be 8](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-the-compare-order-for-bson-types). Per your example, it should be :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student
(id STRUCT<oid:STRING, bsontype:INT>, student_id INT, type STRING, score DOUBLE)
```

Where the output would be something similar to:

```
{"oid":"56d6e0f6ff1f17f74ebbc16c","bsontype":8} 
{"oid":"56d6e0f8ff1f17f74ebbc16d","bsontype":8}
...
```

The above was tested with: MongoDB v3.2.x, mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar, mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.0-rc0.jar, mongo-hadoop-hive-1.5.0-rc0.jar.